# Acrobat Reader refuses to open my .pdf but macOS' Preview does. How to diagnose the reason?

Tags: pdf, error-handling, acrobat

I've built my own .PDF carefully following Adobe PDF specifications. macOS has Preview and that opens and displays the PDF document properly, but Acrobat Reader reports an error, not specified, and does not display the document.

If I open it with Preview and export it from there as another PDF, the result is shown properly by both Preview and Acrobat Reader.

The Preview version is somewhat inexplicably complicated and I cannot determine what difference was done by Preview to allow Acrobat to handle it.

Nor have I been able to find software, even from Adobe's site, that will diagnose the problem.

I have attempted many reasonable variations, additions, etc. on my PDF, to no avail.

What's the secret formula to unlock the beast?

In response to the request, here's an abbreviated copy of the PDF file. All the controlling objects are present but I've deleted portions of the streams to spare you the scrolling. There are two fonts on one page which is an amalgam made of two separate source PDFs, one generated by me and the other from a different supplier, hence the preliminary /Contents objects setting up scaling preliminary to each page object.

Well, after placing the sample here, I get a reject message saying there was an error submitting the edit.

I'm going to try again after eliminating all the compression code in the streams and much of the uncompressed formatting code, to save you from all the scrolling.

(PDF code removed as requested. Stay tuned for update.

Comment: Please share your pdf for analysis. There are many things that might have gone wrong, too many to list in an answer.

Comment: Please don't add the pdf as part of the text but as a binary public share, e.g. on dropbox or Google drive. In the posted stuff above I cannot see whether any offsets are correct, whether required lengths are correct, whether stream contents are correctly compressed,... and in particular I cannot use any programs to test your pdf to get an idea in which direction to check at all.

Comment: One obvious error is in the content stream 10 - you define a path (`3340 3066 m
5711 3066 l
4526 1881 m
4526 4252 l
4526 3066 m`), then you have a text object (`BT ... ET`), and then you try to draw a path (`S`). That's invalid pdf content syntax, even if following Adobe's pdf references and not the ISO pdf specification.

Comment: @mkl Thanks. I shall look into that. Regarding streams and lengths I believe they are correct, but getting an analysis might reveal flaws ignored by Preview. Meanwhile I can alter the position of the path draws (S) and see if that fixes the situation. I am grateful for your help.